# JMeter - Stop sampler execution after some time

Tags: jmeter

I have the following problem - I need to run OS Process Sampler 10 minutes, stop it and do something else.

How can I stop JMeter Sampler (OS Sampler in my case) after some execution time?

Existed JMeter timers do not provide such ability.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add sampler under [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller) configured with 600 seconds

> Runtime Controller controls how long its children how long its children will run. Controller will run its children until configured Runtime(s) is exceeded.